# change the name of android project

Tags: android, eclipse, project

Is there any posibility that I could change the `name of my project` as it appears in `Package Explorer`.I'm using Eclipse IDE.I tried to edit the `string.xml` in `res/value` folder but that won't change it in the Explorer View.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

1. Right click on your project
2. Click "Refactor"
3. Click "Rename..."
4. Enter name!

Or did that not work for you?

Answer (score 15):

if you want to change the name of your android project in Eclipse IDE simply **select your project and press F2 , and then rename it** :).

Or

**right click on your project => Refactor => Rename => enter the name you want**

Answer (score 3):

.project file has the project name where this can be changed too.

Comment: If you need to change out of Eclipse, this worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: is should be welcome to have an example of the corresponded line

Answer (score 1):

right click on your project > Refactor > Rename > enter the new name

and must check on

> Update Refrence
>   if you do not update refrence it will not work

Answer (score 0):

To change your Project name adopt the following steps...

1. Open your project.
2. Select the project.
3. Press F2 and give a new new name to your project.