# How do i Rename my projects in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

Before i begin, this question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9231270/should-renaming-a-project-in-eclipse-also-rename-project-folder-on-file-system). however, my requirement is different. I want to rename my project, for this, i simply bring the project into focus by clicking it, press `Alt+Shift+R` and rename it. This works, but only until i copy my project to my hard drive. I see the old project name again (folder name). It only works in eclipse. how do i rename it properly?

i am using the latest eclipse indigo build.

Comment: hope helps you http://stackoverflow.com/a/6388354/3790150

Comment: @saeed Alt+Shift+R does the same.

Answer (score 0):

Open your .project file from the project folder and change following value in it.
[image]

You need to change to Project name in it.

Another way,

Copy Old project from the Project explorer , and paste it over there, It will ask for new name, give a new name , and done.

Comment: I tried that, i already have the correct name  there "<name>BetterNet</name>"

Answer (score 0):

The solution-

1) Try Darji Jigar's answer. If it doesn't work, try the one that worked for me.

2) copy your project to your hard drive from eclipse, simply rename the project's folder manually (right click-> rename) and import the project back to eclipse, i will not rename it this time.